# Is it possible to reload a MapView?

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I am implementing a MapKit based application. In that I need to reload the map every 10 seconds. Is it there any property to reload the `MKMapView`? Please suggest any idea on this.

Thanks in Advance,
Sekhar Bethalam.

Comment: why do you need to reload it?

Comment: @kiamlaluno:

Hi, That is because the values what I am showing in the map are changed every 5 seconds.

Comment: do you need to reload the map or the stuff on top of it? We need more details of your implementation to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of layer is that? Dynamic?
If you ate adding points the layer will refresh. You cam also use another control like ArcGIS mapviever for iOS that has a refresh method per layer